# Placeholder name to a non-existing photo in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on films searcher in React. The API I'm using does not have full data on every single film, some of them do not have an image. I want to put a placeholder name (possibly an image) where there should a photo, but there is no data. I do not know how to create a function that will check if the image is available. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `propTypes` in your React application, you can add a default there.

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Alternatively, you can use a conditional (ternary) operator in your script as you did in your TitleComponent.jsx.

In that case you just have to import the default image to your component first.

```
import defaultImg form '..images/default.jpg'
```

Comment: I would like to try without propTypes first. 
So how should I check if my API gives me any image?
 `result.Poster ?`   
gives always true
Same with
    `typeof result.Poster != "undefined") ?  `

Comment: In general it would be `<img src={result.Poster ? result.Poster : defaultImg} alt="" />`.

Comment: It seems to me that this always returns result.Poster. Even though there would be no actual image.

Comment: Ok, check what is returned with `console.log(result.Poster)` when there is no image.

Comment: Nothing is returned

Comment: Can you see what value `Poster` without an image has in your data, is it `null`?

Comment: It is `N/A`
I tried using `<img src={result.Poster == N/A ? result.Poster : defaultImg} alt="" />`, but I receive an error "N is not defined and A is not defined". Any idea how I can put it differently?

Comment: It would have to be a string `"N/A"`, so to compare use `result.Poster === "N/A"` or `result.Poster !== "N/A"`